# XAMPP Start automatically on Windows 7 startup

Tags: mysql, apache, xampp

XAMPP Version 3.2.1 installed on Windows 7. It didn't get started automatically on Windows boot.

Tried: looking in `service`, it shows neither Apache nor MySQL.

Answer (score 44):

Try to run Your XAMPP Control Panel as `Run as administrator`, then install Apache and MySQL.

[image]

When XAMPP opens, ensure that Apache and MySQL services are stopped.

[image]

Now just check/tick on Apache and Mysql service module.

[image]

Now Apache and MySQL will be added to window services. You can set these services to start when Windows boots.

Comment: Note that In order to register them as services, you need to stop them first if they are already running.

Answer (score 21):

**Try following Steps for Apache**

- Go to your XAMPP installation folder. Right-click xampp-control.exe. Click "Run as administrator"
- Stop Apache service action port
- Tick this (in snapshot) check box. It will ask if you want to install as service. Click "Yes".
- Go to Windows Services by typing <kbd>Window</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>, then typing `services.msc`
- Enter a new service name as `Apache2` (or similar)
- Set it as automatic, if you want it to run as startup.

**Repeat the steps for the MySQL service**

[image]

Comment: To "Run as administrator", go to your XAMPP installation folder. Right-click `xampp-control.exe`. Click "Run as administrator".

Comment: Notice that this only works on full installations. The light and portible versions will gray out the _service_ checkbox: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20195005/3276634

Answer (score 9):

In addition to MR [Chandru"s](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2707447/chandru) answer above, do these steps after configuring XAMPP:

- open the directory where XAMPP is installed. By default it's installed at  `C:\xampp`
- Create Shortcut to the file `xampp-control.exe`, the XAMPP Control Panel
- Paste it in

> C:\Users\**User-Name**\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start
>   Menu\Programs\Startup

or

> C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\StartUp

The XAMPP Control Panel should now auto-start whenever you reboot Windows.

Answer (score 2):

I just placed a short-cut to the XAMPP control panel in my startup folder.
That works just fine on Window 7.
Start -> All Programs -> Startup. 
There is also an option to start XAMPP control panel minimized, that is very useful for getting a clean unobstructed view of your desktop at start-up.**

Comment: Also the shortcut should be "Run as Administrator".

Answer (score 0):

You can put in this directory your `Xampp control panel shortcut` it will work fine (it will automatically start after windows startup) as @wajahat-hashmi answered above:

```
C:\Users\User-Name\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup
```

**About aditional windows script or programs that we need to run automatically...**

I needed to create some additional scripts to initialize some windows services. If someone has the same need you can put in that same directory, they will all run right after windows startup.

For me, Xampp auto start and other scripts and shortcuts worked fine in windows 8.1, I think it will work fine in any windows version.

I hope it works well for anyone who has the same need.

Answer (score -1):

I am using XAMPP on Win 7 and 8.1 too...it start normally.

Did you try to check the services on **Start > RUN > services.msc**

Find the service: Apache 2.x. (right click) choose Properties. At form "Startup type" choose "Automatically" and Start the service on.

you should reset the PC and check out again.

Do the same with mySQL.

If you can not solve the problem, use XAMPP Panel to start it manually.

Comment: in services.msc, it doesn't show neither apache nor mysql

Comment: If that, you should check your installation. Did you check on the checkbox for Apache and MySQL. You should install xampp by default settings.

If the errors are still on, you should take the picture. I will see and check for you or use the teamviewer (Destop Remote).

XAMPP running on any window version is normal.

Answer (score -1):

Go to the Config button (up right) and select the Autostart for Apache.[image]

Comment: This oly indicates the autostart of the modules when the control panel is started, not when Winblows boots.

Comment: Not relevant to the question.