# XAMPP, localhost wont run

Tags: mysql, xampp

Using windows 7:
I just installed XAMPP for using Apache and MySQL. The problem is that when i type localhost in my browser says cant load the page. I have changed the ports to 8080, and disable the same port for Skype.

Comment: logout from the skype and then try to connect

Comment: Add wampp to the start up services. [here you can find the steps in win 7][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22033083/xampp-start-automatically-on-windows7-startup