# How can I fix authentication?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I installed XAMPP server and it run correctly, but when I went to connect to phpMyAdmin by remote access I have this problem:

[image]

My configuration of config.inc.php is:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';
/* Server parameters */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'my ip address';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['port'] = '3306';

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';
/*$cfg['Servers'][$i]['compress'] = false; */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;
```

Even when I configure a password and I enter by it I have the same problem.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22033083/xampp-start-automatically-on-windows-7-startup/22033578#22033578

Comment: Set `AllowNoPassword` to false.

Comment: @SathishD That is to run MySQL automatically, I don't think that will fix anything.

Comment: Did you allow the incoming connections in your server?

Comment: I don't quite understand: you are able to connect to mysql from the localhost and unable to connect to the same server from external machine?

Comment: The MySQL Server cannot be connected implies it is a problem with the server not accepting incoming connections. You need to contact the server administrator or you need to allow incoming connections from your IP. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @user4035 He's trying to connect to the server MySQL. Check carefully. :)

Comment: Voting to migrate the question to [sf] or [dba.se].

Comment: @PraveenKumar In this case he needs to allow external connections for hist host for the root user in his mysql.

Comment: @user4035 Yes, that's what I am telling. But some geniuses answer like below. :D

Comment: @PraveenKumar Yes, it's a simplified answer. I think, I gave him the code to GRANT access from remote host to root.

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL allow access from your host to root user:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'<your IP or %>' IDENTIFIED BY '<password>';
```

`<your IP or %>` = Is either your IP or "%" symbol to allow access from all the hosts.

`<password>` = your root password

Answer (score -1):

Change:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;
```

to

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = FALSE;
```

Comment: The MySQL Server cannot be connected implies it is a problem with the server not accepting incoming connections. Correct me if I am wrong.