# How to access database from java application without externally putting on mysql server on xampp

Tags: java, php, mysql, jdbc

I had created an java application which uses jdbc to access database,but for this i have to externally put mysql server on using xamppp,but i want to access database without externally making server on,so that my customer need not to bother abot this.He can just open application and store data on database.

Please help i really need this..thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use an embedded database, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/462923/java-embedded-databases-comparison)

There is also an article about autostarting mysql with XAMPP, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22033083/xampp-start-automatically-on-windows-7-startup)

The search function will help you to find further informations.