# XAMPP: Starting MySQL...ok. But unable to start/use The Mysql Process

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp, ubuntu-16.04, lampp

I start xampp the normal way. This is the message i get:

```
sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start
Starting XAMPP for Linux 5.6.20-0...
XAMPP: Starting Apache...already running.
XAMPP: Starting MySQL...ok.
XAMPP: Starting ProFTPD...already running.
```

But the problem is i'm not actual able to use phpMyAdmin, because it seems, Mysql didn't start properly. This is the error that i see in the browser:
[image]

FYI, i'm using Ubuntu 16.04. Also, i've tried several solutions already, like changing the port no. from 3306 to 3307, nothing worked well for me. Also, i need to access my already installed database hosted on port 3306.
The status of all the three processes(including Mysql) at Xampp control panel:[image]

As can be seen, there's no sign of error that i can refer to correct the situation.

Comment: What does the XAMPP control panel show for the status of MySQL? Are you able to connect to MySQL through the command line client? Have you made any changes to the phpMyAdmin configuration or is it still the defaults from the XAMPP installation?

Comment: yes, I tried the CLI way too(Mentioned in the question), there's no error message for the Mysql process. Neither have i made any changes to the phpMyAdmin Configuration.

Comment: I think XAMPP has a separate control panel/status page that shows whether each service is running correctly, such as you can see in the third image at https://stackoverflow.com/a/29331067/2385479. It is interesting that no error is shown here. Perhaps errors are logged elsewhere, perhaps in a file called mysql.log or something similar?

Answer (score 3):

I was facing a similar issue in Ubuntu. My Xampp was installed but the MySQL server wasn't starting in the XAMPP Manager.

Also this resulted in the `localhost/phpmyadmin` page showing:

> error: Cannot connect: Invalid settings.

### The way I solved it is:

1. Inside terminal

   ```
   sudo /etc/init.d/mysql stop
   ```

This will stop the existing mysql service.

2. Then type:

   ```
   sudo /opt/lampp/lampp restart
   ```

Now this should start the mysql server. You can go to `localhost/phpmyadmin` and check it out.